# What is the correct way to load datatables.net plugin into a Vue Webpack app?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, datatables

I am building a Vue Webpack application that depends on [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). The datatable plugin relies on jQuery and as far as I understand, I can't import it into my Vue component like `import datatable from 'datatables.net';`.

As a result, this is how I am currently importing it:

```
<template>
  <table id="datatable" class="table"></table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  beforeCreate() {
    // Fetch jQuery and Datatables JS
    const jQueryElem = document.createElement('script');
    jQueryElem.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
    document.head.appendChild(jQueryElem);

    let dataTableIntervalCount = 0;
    const dataTableInterval = setInterval(() => {
      dataTableIntervalCount += 1;
      if (dataTableIntervalCount === 100) {
        clearInterval(dataTableInterval);
        this.dataTableError = true;
      }

      if (window.$) {
        // Load JS
        const dataTableElem = document.createElement('script');
        dataTableElem.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js');
        document.head.appendChild(dataTableElem);

        // Load CSS
        const dataTablesCss = document.createElement('link');
        dataTablesCss.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        dataTablesCss.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        dataTablesCss.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css');
        document.head.appendChild(dataTablesCss);

        clearInterval(dataTableInterval);
      }
    }, 50);
  },
}
</script>
```

This is causing me quite a lot of pain. I have to check if jQuery has loaded and only then insert the datatable plugin from the CDN. Otherwise, it throws an error in the console.

Once I fetch the datatable plugin, I have to now initialize it on the `#datatable` element inside another `setInterval()` because it takes a few milliseconds to fetch the plugin from CDN. This causes yet another console error sometimes and requires quite a bit of workarounds.

Is there a more reliable way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can share your webpack config file, too. This would especially be helpful if you have customized lines like `var $ = require("jquery");` right in there.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
```

You don't really have to load/package jQuery, you can webpack it as external like so:

```
externals: {
'jquery': 'jQuery',
'vue': 'Vue'
}
```

Then just load jQuery on the page like you would regularly.  Here is the documentation on webpack external: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

(Shameless Plug) I've created jQuery DataTables wrapper here for Vue: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net#usage

See usage and demo for more info on how everything is loaded.